# Windows 7 shows (barely) HDD but Debian 8 does not

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, debian-jessie, external-drive

I have a 2.5" 320gb Seagate hdd that was given to me because it's "broken". I need this drive to work muchly. In Windows 7, connected via external "pluggable" brand HDD dock, the drive shows up as disk 2, unknown, not initialized. I am unable to initialized said disk due to CRC error, unable to assign a mount point and unable to assign a drive letter. Chkdsk says there are no bad sectors and device manager says the device is working fine and has the latest drivers. Debian 8 is unable to detect the drive at all. Period. No utilities or anything can detect the drive in Debian. 
I cannot format, mount or do anything to this drive. Would someone lend me aid?

Comment: How did you run chkdsk if you can't even assign a drive letter? Anyway, the drive might just be broken, but if you're dead set on recovering data you may need to use a different controller board (on the hard drive itself) or even open it up and put the platters in another reader, but that's the specialized and expensive work data recovery guys do (with no guarantees). Could at least try not using an external HD dock, plug it directly into a few different motherboards and see if anything can read it?